# Haftarah for yahrtzeit

Tags: halacha, calendar, haftarah, yahrtzeit

If one's [yahrtzeit](http://www.mykaddish.com/yahrtzeit-basic.html) falls on a day when there is a [haftarah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah), there is a discussion about whether it's a bigger merit for the deceased to recite the [haftarah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah) on that day or before the day of the yahrtzeit, so that the merit will be in place prior.

Does anyone know what is done in practice?  Are there any sources which talk about this in more detail?

Comment: Can you de-jagonify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the Shuls I have Davened in (Yeshivish, Chasidish, Young Israel, Orthodox Union) the person who had Yarzheit either that day or the following week receives Maftir on Shabbos. Regarding Yom Tov they only received it if the Yarzheit is that day.

See Biur Halacha in the Mishna Berura Chelek 2 Siman 137 where it is clearly mentioned that the Chiuv is on the day of the Yarzheit if it comes out on Shabbos.

Comment: Thanks.  I had heard that haftarah might be different than the aliya.  My question about Yom Tov was really the other way around (do you get it on Yom Tov or is it a din in shabbos), but you answered that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd heard the biggest obligation is in fact the last shabbos the person was in this world.  (Don't have sources off-hand.)

Comment: That would be usually represented by the Shabbos before.  But a) what if the yahrtzeit is on shabbos, what's considered the last shabbos?  b) What if the yahrtzeit (or haftarah before) was yom tov?

Comment: What if the last _Shabas_ the person was alive was the 24th of _Cheshvan_ and this year the 24th of _Cheshvan_ is a Tuesday?

Comment: @msh210 Better yet, what if the last Shabbat he was in the world was the 30th of _Cheshvan_!

Comment: @msh210 Ok so it turns out 30 Cheshvan can't be Shabbat and 24 Cheshvan can't be Tuesday.