# Maftir aliyoh for one who has Yahrzeit in the coming week – why?

Tags: haftarah, yahrtzeit, maftir

There seems to be a custom in Ashkenazi shuls that someone who has Yahrzeit in the coming week is given maftir and haftorah.
I have been told that the 7 other aliyos are more important than the maftir. This makes the minhag difficult to understand.
What is the source of this minhag?

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/maftir-an-honor) is highly related.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2941/759